# C# compare two objects of unknown types (including reference and value types)

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible in C# to compare two objects of unknown types, (including both reference and value types) using their type comparators if they exist?

The goal is to write a function that would have a signature like this:

```
public bool Compare(object a, object b)
{
     // compare logic goes here
}
```

Which would return

```
Compare(100d, 100d) == true
Compare(100f, 100f) == true
Compare("hello", "hello") == true
Compare(null, null) == true 
Compare(100d, 101d) == false
Compare(100f, null) == false

// Use type comparators where possible, i.e.:
Compare(new DateTime(2010, 12, 01), new DateTime(2010, 12, 01)) == true
Compare(new DateTime(2010, 12, 01), new DateTime(2010, 12, 02)) == false
Compare(new DateTime(2010, 12, 01), null) == false
```

Is there a generic approach to solving this problem that would work for any type of object?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can use the static `object.Equals(object x, object y)` method and not bother writing your method at all. That will handle nulls appropriately, and delegate to an implementation of `object.Equals(object)` associated with either `x` or `y`... it *shouldn't* matter which, as `Equals` is meant to be symmetric.

Note that this *doesn't* use the == operators for any type - operators can't be overridden, only overloaded (which means they're chosen at *compile-time*, not *execution-time*. In most cases `Equals` should do what you want. In some cases, == may not be overloaded even though `Equals` is overridden... but I've never known the reverse to be true in any types I've worked with.

Note that using this approach will *box* any value types...

EDIT: Removed section about effectively reimplementing - poorly - `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`. See Marc's answer for more. This won't help you if you can't use a generic type, of course.

One final point: I *wouldn't* call your method `Compare`. That name is usually associated with *ordering* values rather than comparing them for equality.

Comment: Surely the latter will only work for reference types as you will have to have `where T : class` in order to use `v1 == null` so preventing value type comparision.

Comment: Any reason not to use `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` here? That would make things more general (`IEquatable<T>` constraint not required), but not force boxing unless absolutely necessary, wouldn't it?

Comment: @aqwert: Nope. It just always evaluates to null for value types.

Comment: @Ani: Merely a brain freeze :) Marc has now covered that in his answer, so I've edited my stuff out.

Comment: Is there a way to make this also work for primitive types such as int, long, etc.

Comment: @Mensur: It will already work for primitive types. Just use `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` and all will be fine.

Comment: Equals is meant to be symmetric? This seems not be guaranteed: `2.Equals(2.0)` vs `2.0.Equals(2)` ... Good grief! How to get there everywhere? :(

Answer (score 21):

A reasonable option is is to work with generics, i.e.

```
public bool Compare<T>(T a, T b) {...}
```

You won't need to specify the `T` in your code, as the compiler will usually be able to figure it out (i.e. your existing samples would work "as-is")

For the implementation:

```
bool equal = EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(x, y);
```

(for generic type `T`)

but *actually* I would avoid the word `Compare`, as that is used elsewhere to mean `<` / `==` / `>` - so I might have:

```
public static bool Equals<T>(T a, T b) {
    return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(a, b);
}
```

This:

- avoids boxing when T is a struct
- handles nulls / `Nullable<T>` correctly
- supports `IEquatable<T>`
- or falls back to regular `Equals`

it does **not** use the `==` operator, but MiscUtil has an `Operator` class that *will*, via

```
bool equal = Operator.Equal<T>(x,y);
```

(note this latter will fail if `T` doesn't have an `==` operator, although thinking about it, it could use `EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals` as a fallback; it just doesn't)

---

For completeness, note that `Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(x,y)` handles comparison operations.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer, both your own and Jon Skeet's answers work for my particular use case.

Answer (score 6):

How about `object.equals(x, y)`? This will accept null values as well.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
if (a == null && b == null) return true;
if (a == null && b != null) return false;
return (a.equals(b));
```

?

Answer (score -4):

I'm not 100% sure if this works in all cases, but give it a try

```
public bool Compare(object a, object b)
{
    return a.Equals(b);
}
```

Comment: This will cause a NullReferenceException if a is null.