# Comparing object of type "Object" in C#

Tags: c#, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

I am trying to implement a tree data structure in `C#`, which I've done a 100 times in `C++`
But here when I'm trying to keep the Tree generic in order to accept any data type, I've made each `Node` have it's data in an object of type `Object`, as shown here:

```
    public class Node
    {
        public object Data;
        public Node Right;
        public Node Left;

        public Node(object value)
        {
            NodeContent = value;
            Right = Left = null;
        }
    }
```

But when I'm trying to implement the `insert`, I need to compare two objecs of type `Object` in order to know whether to insert a new node on the left or right side of the current node. When I try to check this

```
    if(value < childPtr.Data)
```

where `value` is the value to be inserted, I get an error saying that I can't compare two objects of type `Object`. So is there a way around this?

Comment: If you want to make the tree generic, then you should use Generics! Make it a `class Node<T> where T : IComparable<T>` and use `public T Data;`. Then you can do `value.CompareTo(childPtr.Data)`.

Comment: When you say `value < childPtr.Data` you're already implying the object is a value type, so why use `object` then?

Comment: @AlexanderDerck I used object so I can keep the Data variable generic, so the tree will accept any data type.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332635/c-sharp-compare-two-objects-of-unknown-types-including-reference-and-value-type

Comment: If I create two new objects, `var o1 = new object(); var o2 = new object();`... which of those is "bigger" than the other? What I insert a floating point number and then a string - how would you compare those? If you want to do this generically, you should use generics... at which point you can add a constraint that `T` implements `IComparable<T>`...

Comment: @Blorgbeard that makes sense to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that `Data` can be any type. Your design allows you to put multiple types into the same tree. So one node might have a `string` and the other might have a `double`, and a third could have a reference to a user-defined type. If you make the `Node` constructor take an `IComparable` instance, you're assuming that all of the items in the tree will be of the same type, or that their `IComparable` interface implementations know how to compare values of all possible data types.

In short, whereas what you did will work, it's not at all type safe.

What you have is a very C-like thing to do. In C++, you'd use templates to avoid this kind of abomination. In C#, you use generics.

I echo the suggestion made in the comments: if you want a generic data structure, *make a generic data structure*. Using the built-in collections, for example, if you want a list of integers you write:

```
var list_of_integers = new List<int>();
```

And if you want a list of strings:

```
var list_of_strings = new List<string>();
```

If you want to create a generic tree collection, you'd start with:

```
public class MyGenericTree<T>
{
    public class Node
    {
        public T Data;
        public Node Left;
        public Node Right;

        public Node(T data)
        {
            Data = data;
        }
    }

    private readonly IComparer<T> _comparer;

    public MyGenericTree(IComparer<T> comparer = null)
    {
        _comparer = comparer ?? Comparer<T>.Default;
    }
}
```

And you create it with:

```
var myTree = new MyGenericTree<string>(); // or int, or whatever type
```

If you want a custom comparison function, you write:

```
// Create a tree that stores case-insensitive strings
var myTree = new MyGenericTree<string>(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

This forces the `Data` to always be of a compatible type. And you either use the default comparer for that type, or the comparer interface that you pass to the constructor.

And when doing the comparisons, it's:

```
int a = _comparer.Compare(node1, node2);
if (a < 0)
    // node1 < node2
else if (a > 0)
    // node1 > node2
else
    // node1 == node2
```

If you really do want to store untyped `object` references in the tree, you can easily write:

```
var myTree = new MyGenericTree<object>(some_object_comparer);
```

Although why you'd want to do such a thing is a bit of a mystery.

I know that the generics look a little weird to start, but after a day or so of working with them, you grasp the idea that they're quite flexible as well as being type safe.

Comment: I strongly agree with Jim. Mine answer was just quick fix while Jim's leads to better approach. Generics fits perfectly well for the problem described.

Comment: @Jim Mischel Thank you, this actually makes more sense. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Since you require comparison from your data a better approach would be :

```
public class Node
{
    public IComparable Data;
    public Node Right;
    public Node Left;

    public Node(IComparable value)
    {
        Data = value;
        Right = Left = null;
    }
}
```

and later you can do:

```
if(value.CompareTo(childPtr.Data) < 0)
```

Comment: I'm guessing CompareTo() returns 0 when they're equal, less that 0 when value is less that Data and greater than 0 when Data is greater than value. Am I right?

Comment: I really want to downvote this answer, not because it's incorrect but because it's perpetuating a really terrible development practice. Unfortunately, despite it being a horrible solution to the problem of building a "generic" data structure, it solves the OP's immediate problem. I do want to stress, though, that it would have been much better to dissuade the OP from continuing down his misguided path.